# AssetTrapped: I teleported 1499 DOT from Polkadot to AssetHub but it has not arrived

Tags: xcm

https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/20098119-2

"AssetsTrapped" (1,499 DOT!!)

So trying to claim an asset:

[image]

here is the encoded call

```
0x6303030c1804000000000700e40b5402000013000000000700e40b54020100000d010000010100d05b3519d4062c0f60d2e4e900755c30e9fa6df0782642be2e1482939a1b423b91019101
```

but i get an error:

1001 would exhaust the block limits...

It seems that the required call is too large to fit in a block?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this fails because `pallet_xcm::execute()` [is configured with Weight::MAX](https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/runtimes/blob/2e269677dda059ac1085b4168a15d58912960a6e/relay/polkadot/src/weights/pallet_xcm.rs#L134) for Polkadot.

This happens because Polkadot runtime is [configured to disallow executing](https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/runtimes/blob/2e269677dda059ac1085b4168a15d58912960a6e/relay/polkadot/src/xcm_config.rs#L298) arbitrary XCM messages.

There is a [dedicated extrinsic for claiming assets](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/3403) being rolled out with upcoming runtimes v1.2.0 release & upgrade.

Unfortunately, you will have to wait for the upgrade before being able to claim your trapped assets :(

Either that, or go through governance, but I think that'll be even slower.